# android focusing buttons in horizontal scroll view

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android and I am having an issue I have a horizontal scroll view with buttons in it decipting age where the user clicks on the button corresponding to his/her age. Everything goes well and I get a horizontal scroll view with buttons from 10-99 with the starting button as 10. All I need is to have buttons being displayed in between 30-40 range in the horizontal scroll view, instead of being displayed from the first button(i.e age 10 button) on wards. ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done by using button.requestFocus(int direction) and button.requestChildFocus(View child,View Focus)

Answer (score 0):

Use function ***scrollTo(int x, int y)***, for example:

```
myScrollView.scrollTo(150,0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Primoz!that was quick!

Comment: Actually it was you being late :) But no probs there pal, glad to help.